# How to change Address in Swedish Tax Agency (Skatteverket)?

Tags: sweden

Is it possible to change the address in the Swedish Tax Agency (Skatteverket) online? Can it be done from abroad?

Answer (score 6):

It can be done online if you use [e-legitimation](http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/sjalvservice/allaetjanster/omelegitimation/utgivareavelegitimation.4.18e1b10334ebe8bc8000736.html).  This is provided through banks, so as long as you have a bank-account and an operating system supported by your banks e-legitimation, you can do it from anywhere.

Otherwise, it can only be done on paper.

Comment: I'd never heard of e-legitimation before. BankID is the more colloquial term

Comment: It looks like Skatteverket's change of address can be found in My Pages > Civil Registration > Notification of Move, or Mina sidor > Folkbokföring > Flyttanmälan in Swedish

Comment: Here's the URL as of October 2023: https://www7.skatteverket.se/portal/flyttanmalan/